# Should I invest time in learning Groovy/Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm a Flex developer with some JavaScript experience. Would like to extend my expertize. In past I played with some other Grails' like frameworks like RoR and Django. I have a very little knowledge of Java though but I'd like to learn it too(will Grails help me with that?)

Answer (score 6):

Grails won't help you learn Java, although it may lead you "down the path" to Spring and Hibernate. If you want to learn Java, learn Java. As Bozho says, Spring MVC would be a more logical choice if Java-the-language is a specific goal.

If the goal is Java-the-ecosystem, Grails *may* be one way to get there, but I'd caution that when things go wrong in Grails/Groovy/Spring/Hibernate, they'll go *specatularly* wrong, and without the underlying knowledge, making progress on those issues may be... problematic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn Java, go with Spring MVC first. Then grails will come naturally (it is based on spring-mvc)